# How to make a button in an extension redirect the user to a certain page

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, segue

**Overview**
I'm building a custom keyboard extension in swift and I want to make a button redirect the user to a certain page in its parent application.

**What I'm doing**
I created a button in my keyboard that is supposed to take the user to the application and it works.

```swift
 @objc func openURL(_ url: URL) {
          return
      }
   func openApp(_ urlstring:String) {
        
        var responder: UIResponder? = self as UIResponder
        let selector = #selector(openURL(_:))
        while responder != nil {
            if responder!.responds(to: selector) && responder != self {
                responder!.perform(selector, with: URL(string: urlstring)!)
                return
            }
            responder = responder?.next
        }
    }
@IBAction func openShop(_ sender: Any) {
  openApp ("myapppurl")
  parent?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Shop", sender: self)//Shop is the identifier of a segue in my app.
}
```

And of course I added this to my the info.plist file in my app.[image: )]

**Problem**
When I press the button, it takes me to the app but it shows the main vc, not the page i need.

**Question**
How do I make the button take me directly to the desired vc?

Answer (score 0):

You can't performSegue to container app from extension. In order to performSegue to work view needs to be in foreground. When you are performing Segue, container App is in background and that's why it is not doing anything.

You will need to handle deep-linking in container App.

Add destination inside your openApp URL "myapppurl//shop"

This should trigger `openURL[enter link description here][1]` in container app.

and URL param should give you requested destination. There you can handle logic to deep-linking.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering and thank you very much for your answer... Anyway. It's not clear for me where I have to add this "myapppurl//shop" and what shop is in your answer. Is it the identifier or the view controller name?

Answer (score -1):

You can set USERDEFAULTS value , when opening app check it, and clear.